# Text alignnment on text that has been rotated using CSS

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to align all of the text in a span (vertically and horizontally) so that it's uniform. However for some reason the third (green) `team` column has a different placement inside the `col` div than the rest of the `team` divs as you can see using Firebug or the like.

How can i fix this issue and is it related to the fact the divs have been rotated or is it something else?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n0L7768c/

```css
.counter {
  background-color: #653d24;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: "Patrick Hand", arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 15px 0 15px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 100px;
  z-index: 99999999;
  bottom: -0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.counter h3 {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/springfield/images/title-bg.png");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 88px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 88px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: -41px;
  width: 305px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.counter .col {
  width: 75px;
  height: 172px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.counter .team {
  font-size: 20px;
  left: -22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  transform-origin: 49% 52%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 49% 52%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 49% 52%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 49% 52%;
  -o-transform-origin: 49% 52%;
  width: 119px;
}
.counter .score {
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
span.blue {
  color: #3597d0;
}
span.orange {
  color: #ff9900;
}
span.green {
  color: #99cc00;
}
span.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.counter .col.blue {
  background-color: #3597d0;
}
.counter .col.orange {
  background-color: #ff9900;
}
.counter .col.green {
  background-color: #99cc00;
}
.counter .col.red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.team > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.show {
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom 2s;
  -moz-transition: bottom 2s;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 2s;
  -ms-transition: bottom 2s;
  -o-transition: bottom 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter hidden-mobile">
  <div class="scores">
    <div class="col blue">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Miners (2nd)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">341</div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
    <div class="col orange">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Brewers (1st)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">
        456
      </div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
    <div class="col green">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Foresters (3rd)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">
        259
      </div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
    <div class="col red">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Potters (4th)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">
        69
      </div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
  </div>
  <!-- .scores -->
</div>
<!-- .counter -->
```

Comment: This is what I see on [Firefox](http://s18.postimg.org/43b2vqma1/Forefox.png) and this on [Chrome](http://s16.postimg.org/bz42yjumd/chrome.png).

Comment: @Nikki, you should look into strategies to structure your css.  Here's a [css style guide](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css#declaration-order) you can choose to adopt which groups css properties together. That was you won't accidentally overwrite them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.team > span` like this:

```css
.team > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
.counter {
  background-color: #653d24;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: "Patrick Hand", arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 15px 0 15px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 100px;
  z-index: 99999999;
  bottom: -0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.counter h3 {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/springfield/images/title-bg.png");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 88px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -41px;
  width: 305px;
  line-height: 88px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
.counter .col {
  width: 75px;
  height: 172px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.counter .team {
  font-size: 20px;
  left: -22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 119px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-270deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
          transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 49% 52%;      
     -moz-transform-origin: 49% 52%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 49% 52%;
       -o-transform-origin: 49% 52%;
          transform-origin: 49% 52%;
}
.counter .score {
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

span.blue   { color: #3597d0; }
span.orange { color: #ff9900; }
span.green  { color: #99cc00; }
span.red    { color: #ff0000; }

.counter .col.blue   { background-color: #3597d0; }
.counter .col.orange { background-color: #ff9900; }
.counter .col.green  { background-color: #99cc00; }
.counter .col.red    { background-color: #ff0000; }

.team > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.show {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 2s;
     -moz-transition: bottom 2s;
      -ms-transition: bottom 2s;
       -o-transition: bottom 2s;
          transition: bottom 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter hidden-mobile">
  <div class="scores">
    <div class="col blue">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Miners (2nd)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">341</div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
    <div class="col orange">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Brewers (1st)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">
        456
      </div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
    <div class="col green">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Foresters (3rd)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">
        259
      </div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
    <div class="col red">
      <div class="team">
        <span>Potters (4th)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- .team -->
      <div class="score">
        69
      </div>
      <!-- .score -->
    </div>
    <!-- .col -->
  </div>
  <!-- .scores -->
</div>
<!-- .counter -->
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the job. Just curious, how did you come to the conclusion this was the issue so fast? Have you dealt with this problem before in the past? Thanks!

Comment: @NikkiMather, remember to upvote answers you find helpful and accept answers that best answer your question for this and other questions on stack overflow.